# ScrollView not updated

Tags: swiftui

ScrollView does not update after loading data. ScrollView successfully displays data only after I switch to another screen and come back.
https://youtu.be/0q3R6LaKbnE

For asynchronous image loading, use: https://github.com/dmytro-anokhin/url-image

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class NewsAPI: ObservableObject {

    @Published var articles: Articles = [Article]()

    init() {
        guard let url: URL = URL(string: "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=ru&apiKey=376a97643c6c4633afe57427b71e8ebd") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                guard let json = data else { return }
                let welcome = try JSONDecoder().decode(ModelNews.self, from: json)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.articles = welcome.articles!
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

```
struct CardList: View {

    @ObservedObject var newsAPI: NewsAPI = NewsAPI()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    ForEach(self.newsAPI.articles, id: \.self) { i in
                        CardView(article: i)
```

Comment: xcode 11.2 last beta, ios 13.2 last beta

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem. The updating works fine, the problem is something else! 
I've struggled for hours to solve this and I've found a solution.

If you provide default values from the same type or a view, which is only shown, when the array is empty, everything is working as it should. Seems like the view have the wrong size, if the array is empty, so you don't see anything, because the size isn't changing with the update of the content.

**In short words:** Provide a default value or an alternative view, which is shown, if the array is empty.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Good catch Dibay! also providing a fixed size to the VStack inside of the ScrollView it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You could test it without the dispatchqueue. I had a similar issue on a list and got it to work when i removed the Dispatchqueue.

Just `self.articles = welcome.articles!`.

Comment: This did not fix the problem, only added a warning: "Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates."

Comment: @ДмитрийЛисин can you share more code? The struct Article might be interesting to reproduce the error.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/lisindima/d57c853470e10167a38cf384de60c730

Comment: @ДмитрийЛисин I was not able to reproduce your problem since i dont know the complete code. It may have something to do with the way you are loading images.
Try it without loading images, maybe that helps to locate the problem.

Comment: This is the first thing I checked, but it also did not change anything. Perhaps this is due to the fact that the scrollview is in tabview and it is displayed first at startup ...

Comment: Tabview could be the problem but not necessarily.